# Javascript syntax issue

Tags: javascript

Here is my [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/26/)

Its on the Phone method, no the name one

Now is this line right? I only want it to be true if the first 3 letters are 087

```
var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,2) == (087);


 if (BlankPass || LessThan10 ||  RightStarting3 || GreaterThan10 || (HasSpaces > 0)) 
 {

    document.getElementById('Phone').style.background = "red";
    return false;
 } 
    else {
    document.getElementById('Phone').style.background = "white";
    document.getElementById("PhoneTick").style.visibility="visible";
    return true;

 }
```

Comment: `087` is not a string but the number which is equivalent to `87`. If you want a string, use a string literal like `"087"`.

Comment: @Gumbo, while it's certainly good to change the comparison to `=== '087'`, loosely comparing a string to `087` should generally provide the correct results. OP narrowly misses running into issues with octal numbers (`077` is the number `63` in decimal, which is misleading to beginners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value.substring(x)` returns a string and `087` and `87` mean the same to javascript interpreter. You should change one of the datatypes so that they match...

Either the substring to an integer:

`var RightStarting3 = parseInt(value.substring(0,2)) == 87;`

Or the value you're comparing against to a string:

`var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) == "087";`

Secondly -- you are invoking `ValidateName()` immediately (in your assignment to `NamePass`). Is this really necessary? There will be empty values on page load.

Comment: can you tell me why the first '086' will work but the other wont? var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) == ('086' || '087');

Comment: `('086' || '087')` will **always** return `'086'` -- it gets instantly short-circuited by the javascript interpreter because the static `'086'` value will never ever be false. If you're trying to test either value, you need to write: `var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) == '086' || value.substring(0,3) == '087'` Alternatively, you could store the string representation `'086'` or `'087'` in a variable, and test it once.

Answer (score 3):

```
var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) === ('087');
```

Comment: Hm can you explain why '000000000' works aswell as '0878888888' ?
http://jsfiddle.net/UTtxA/27/

Answer (score 1):

I think with the javascript substring(x,y) method, the y value is the value at which to stop the selection. So in your example the first 3 characters will not be selected and instead the first 2 characters will be selected.

```
var a = "123";

// this returns "12"
alert(a.substring(0,2));
```

You probably want to use `var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) == ('087');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

KingKongFrom's answer is correct, I would add that you should make sure that `value` (whatever that is) isn't null first, cause if you try to call `substring` on null it will thrown an exception and die.

Comment: can you tell me why the first '086' will work but the other wont?
var RightStarting3 = value.substring(0,3) == ('086' || '087');